# How do I send metadata from ExoPlayer to bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, metadata, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm trying to send **fixed metadata** through bluetooth on my radio app, basically I would put the **radio name as title**, and the **radio slogan as subtitle**, so there isn't anything dynamic involved.
I have tried searching for other answers on StackOverflow but they're related to ICY streams or getting the metadata from ExoPlayer itself.

The stream itself provides the metadata when listening **directly** through FM or a **stream player** (for example, VLC), but it fails to display when going through my app.

This is my code, from what I've managed to understand I should send the metadata inside the brackets after 'addMetadataOutput'.

```
        extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);
        defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "mediaPlayerSample"), defaultBandwidthMeter);
        mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://sr11.inmystream.it/proxy/radiocircuito29?mp=/stream"), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
        
        player.addMetadataOutput();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of dependencies in this area, it's not just a case of sending values, you are going to need to handle notifications and media sessions.

For that, you are going to need some additional Exoplayer extensions.  Specifically:   MediaSessionCompat, MediaSessionConnector  and connect them up to to your Exoplayer and NotificationManager.

```
mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat( this, Constants.PLAYBACK_CHANNEL_ID );
mPlayerNotificationManager.setMediaSessionToken( mMediaSession.getSessionToken() );
mMediaSession.setActive( true );
mMediaSessionConnector = new MediaSessionConnector( mMediaSession );
mMediaSessionConnector.setPlayer( mPlayer );
```

Once you have these, you also need to implement a DescriptionAdapter class

```
public class MyDescriptionAdater implements PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter
```

This will create the interface to populate with your static metadata.  You then need to wire this up to you PlayerNotificationManager using setMediaDescriptionAdapter